# Why this constraint is crucial in a Lagrange multiplier problem?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Consider we need to find the max. and min. values of this function $ f(x,y)=xy $ subject to the constraint $x^2-y=12$.Why it is necessary to assume that $ y\leq0$?

Comment: Did you construct the Lagrangian and compute it's derivatives? It should be clear then.

Comment: @Mattos yes i did so and while i am solving, I didnot make use this assumption , but i was wondering why this assumption is stated in the question.

Comment: After taking derivatives of the Lagrangian, you should get a condition that $y + 2x^2 = 0$...